# New dialogs cause window to disappear in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, dialog, caliburn.micro

I'm running WPF application which can show windows and dialogs on top of the main screen of the application (.NET Framefork 4.7.2)
I use IWindowManager interface to call ShowWindow and ShowDialog.

When I want to show some window

```
Execute.OnUIThread(ShowPostProcessingLoadingMsg);
    private void ShowPostProcessingLoadingMsg()
    {
        Logger.Info("PostProcessingToolViewModel: ShowPostProcessingLoadingMsg()");
        if (_processingProgressMsg != null)
        {
            Logger.Warn("PostProcessingToolViewModel: ShowPostProcessingLoadingMsg() Loading msg was actibe already, closing it and creating a new one.");
            _processingProgressMsg.TryClose();
        }
        _processingProgressMsg = new LoadingMessageViewModel()
        {
            ShowProgressRing = Visibility.Hidden,
            ShowProgressBar = Visibility.Visible,
            LoadingVisualState = LoadingVisualState.Mini
        };
        _progress = _processingProgressMsg.Progress;
        _progress?.Report(0);
        _updateProgressText = _processingProgressMsg.SetMessage;
        _WindowManager?.ShowWindow(_processingProgressMsg);
    }
```

And during it I show a dialog on other thread -

```
    private void ShowPopupInDesktop(BatteryViewModel batteryPopupViewModel)
    {
        _logger.Info("BatteryViewModel::ShowPopupInDesktop: Going to show battery dialog");
        _isPopupOpen = true;
        SetPopupPosition(batteryPopupViewModel);
        _windowManager.ShowDialog(batteryPopupViewModel, BatteryPopupViewContextName);
    }
```

Then the window which I showed disappears.

I don't know how to keep the window opened and why does the dialog make it disappear.

Comment: Can you share the complete sample?

Comment: Which application framework are you using?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - This is a very big project, I cannot share it, but I added the complete methods

Comment: @Eldar .NET Framefork 4.7.2

Comment: I was asking `Caliburn.Micro` part.

Comment: Caliburn.Micro 1.5.1

Comment: On ShowDialog documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.showdialog?view=netframework-4.8
"ShowDialog shows the window, disables all other windows in the application"
Maybe "disables" means closing the opened window?